# The openFDA API supports searching by range in date not working?

Tags: api, openfda

I would like to create an URL, **that shows me all reports from the MAUDE database from December with the product key 'MQB'.** I created the this URL as an attempt:

```
https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?search=product_code:MQB%20event_date_posted:[2022-12-01%20TO%202022-12-31]&limit=1000
```

I have also tried without the hyphens between the year, month and day, so: `...[20221201+TO+20221231]&limit=1000`.

Both behave the same, they display all reports from all months. **The date limit doesn't really apply.**

Has anyone had the **same or a similar problem?**

The **syntax of the query** is [described on the official site, here](https://open.fda.gov/apis/dates-and-ranges/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AND` if you wish to have both be true. For example, this [link show one device recall](https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?search=product_code:MQB%20AND%20event_date_posted:%5B2018-06-01%20TO%202022-12-31%5D&limit=1000).

The two basic uses of search are:

- `search=field:value+AND+field:value` for records that match both values.
- `search=field:value+field:value` for records that match either of the values.